# Is it possible to execute an event when flutter app loads instead of waiting for user input like onPressed?

Tags: flutter

I have a `mixin` that will add files to a riverpod provider (this may not be relevant) and set some other providers based on the file types. The mixin function is called from several places depending on how files are entered such as a file picker or files dragged into the window. This works great but now I am trying to implement the ability to add files when the app starts. So if a user opens an associated file type from explorer for the app or if they select files and choose `open with...` (in Windows), I will get a list of files in `void main(List<String> arguments) {}`. My problem is that I don't know when or where I can pass these files to the existing mixin that is responsible for adding files to the `StateNotifier`.

I have thought about trying to pass those files to the StateNotifier in a `ref.read()` when the app launches but 1) i don't know if that would work and 2) if it does work, I will be duplicating the mixin code for this specific task and would rather stick with the mixin.

Is there a way to "force" a call to the mixin's function instead of having to wait for a user event like a button press?

Answer (score 0):

The best place to add your `mixin` is during `initialization` of `provider`.

Example:

```
final sampleNotifierProvider = StateNotifierProvider(
  (ref) => SampleNotifier(ref.watch(sampleRepositoryProvider)),
);


class SampleNotifier extends StateNotifier<WeatherState> {
  final SampleRepository _sampleRepository;

  SampleNotifier(this._sampleRepository) : super(SampleInitial()){
    //  <mixin>  Add your mixin here
  }
}
```